# how to fetch the features that are making up the image of a dynamic or tiled service ?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, tiles, dynamic-layer

It it possible to to know the position of the points that an image  coming from dynamic or tiled services contain. 
I need this to implement a custom mouse-over event for tiled/dynamic services.

Comment: I think the only real way to do this is to have a mouse move event handler that queries the server for features in that area.  If not, you might be able to load a snapshot of features in a hidden feature layer in the application and then query against that.  Just make sure it updates as the extent changes.

Comment: Thank tou. However I think that hidden feature layer do not produce events

Comment: Also,  loading all points is not an option, since I will have to bring in the front 100K ++ points. That's why I need to bring my data as an image.

Comment: In these examples tha are using wax and tile json in can be done. However tile json seems not to be supported from arcgis server

Comment: The FeatureLayer object maxes out at 500 features or so.  If you only need it at a closer extent, it may work for you.  Other than that, I am not sure of an effective way to do it.  you might be able to query the layer initially and keep feature bounding boxes in memory to compare a mouse move against, but that would be a lot of storage.